# I have a problem to insert into mysql all data from inputs and foreach loop ( only one data enters mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, insert

Just the last data enters mysql with this program :

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "bern...";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "base";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo $_POST["quantité"];
$a = $_POST["trekking"];

foreach ($a as $v) {
    echo $v . "<br />\n";
    $sql =  "INSERT INTO Donnesmi (commentaire) VALUES ('$v')";
}
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Would you have a solution for this basic concern , thank you very much

Comment: A great tip is never execute a query inside a loop. Instead, if you can, build the query inside the loop, and execute it once, afterwards. I would also council against including accents in table/column identifiers, but that's just me.

Comment: @Strawberry :) Thats almost what the OP is doing :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly I got lost in curly brackets.

Comment: You are open to SQL injections. You should parameterize this. I also see no reason for `$a`. `foreach($_POST["trekking"] as `

Answer (score 1):

the reason for your actual problem is

```
foreach ($a as $v) {
     echo $v . "<br />\n";
     $sql =  "INSERT INTO Donnesmi (commentaire) VALUES ('$v')";
 }
```

so you overwrite your $sql variable each time, and at the end of the loop you are left with the last value.  but see the comments for the various issues/suggestions with this code

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: 5th Mar 2019**

issue with your code was, since within for loop $sql always gets overwritten only the final $sql is executed.

As pointed out by @jameson2012, one optimum way to do this would be,

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "bern...";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "base";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo $_POST["quantité"];
$a = $_POST["trekking"];


$values = [];
foreach ($a as $v) {
  echo $v . "<br />\n";
  $values[] = "('$v')";
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO Donnesmi (commentaire) VALUES " . emplode(',', $values);
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

basically rather than running multiple insert statements, you build a one single statement and execute it.

========================================================================
Old Answer

You must execute SQL inside foreach. Refer below.

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "bern...";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "base";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo $_POST["quantité"];
$a = $_POST["trekking"];

foreach ($a as $v) {
  echo $v . "<br />\n";
  $sql =  "INSERT INTO Donnesmi (commentaire) VALUES ('$v')";

  if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
      echo "New record created successfully";
  } else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
  }
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: "You must execute SQL inside foreach" is not great advice, it's always better to execute outside a foreach so you can only execute once.  A simple way to do this would be inside the forloop to create an array like $values[] = '(' . $v . ')'; and then use implode(',',$values) to create the string of inserts.  However this whole thing needs to implement PDO (which you can also generate inside the loop along with a bind array and then execute once outside the loop)

Comment: thank you all for contribution .Use of dryize solution with $values = [] and implode works fine .